# Is Uniqueness Theorem in electrostatics valid if i replace a point charge by a surface charge

Tags: electromagnetism

What I understand from the derivation is that if I can replicate the boundary conditions for any charge distribution I'm guaranteed to get the same value of potential everywhere inside the volume. Naturally, I thought of replacing a point charge centred inside a spherical volume with a conducting sphere, with the same charge, also centred in the volume. Clearly the potential inside the sphere doesn't match with that near the original charge.

Comment: > *"if I can replicate the boundary conditions for any charge distribution I'm guaranteed to get the same value of potential everywhere inside the volume"* I think you misunderstood something. The boundary conditions are usually meant for potential, not for charge distribution. Where did you read this?

Comment: Wikipedia, and I replicated the potential on the spherical volume I'm assuming. Let me rephrase the question. If i take a spherical volume V with its surface S and radius r. Now if I centre a point charge q or a conducting sphere(R, q), the potential at S is kq/r in both cases. Hence I replicated the potential at the boundary conditions. I should get the same potential everywhere inside the volume V. But I'm not getting the same potential inside the spherical conductor charge in the second situation. Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: I think the potential value on the boundary determines potential inside only in case there is no charge inside the region. Then the potential inside obeys the Laplace equation and uniqueness theorem applies. But in your case you have charge inside and are comparing two different charge distributions - in that case, uniqueness theorem cannot apply, these are two different physical situations, so solution to the potential inside will be different.

Comment: When the question of uniqueness is raised in electrostatics, it is this: given full specification of charge distribution inside and boundary condition on potential on the boundary surface, is the potential inside everywhere in the region determined, or can there be several solutions? The answer for fixed distribution and boundary condition of Dirichlet's type is that potential is determined uniquely. But different charge distributions give different solutions.